# Missing Master Pages when using Web Deployment Project

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, web-deployment-project

I am trying to deploy an ASP.NET 3.5 Web Application to my production server and I am using the Web Deployment Project for this purpose. I have a folder named MasterPages in the root of the application which contains all the master page files. When I build this project in the release mode and deploy it on to the server I am getting the below error message:

**Directory 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MasterPages' does not exist. Failed to start monitoring file changes.**

I am using ASP.NET AJAX and the ToolkitScriptManager is on the master pages. I have noticed that the MasterPages folder is missing from the release build. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Do all the other files get deployed? Do you see marker aspx files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual problem was with the CombineScripts property of the ToolkitScriptManager. It was set to true but when I set it to false everything works.

Comment: plus one for coming back with an answer and building up the knowledge base.